# specifying ID in fxml file to use getElementById in controller

Tags: java, user-interface, dom, javafx, fxml

i'm trying to learn to use DOM Parser in javafx to edit the FXML file in my project using buttons in the UI. i'm having problems figuring out how it works and i can't find tutorials for this so here's some simple code that doesn't work:

FXML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>

<HBox fx:controller="com.example.dom.HelloController" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <VBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="20.0" >
        <Button></Button>
    </VBox>
    <VBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="20.0" >
        <Button></Button>
    </VBox>

</HBox>
```

main:

```
package com.example.dom;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class test extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\wollen.LAPTOP-2NNG87NA\\IdeaProjects\\DOM\\src\\main\\resources\\com\\example\\dom\\test.fxml")) {

            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = db.parse(is);
            doc.getElementsByTagName("VBox").item(0).removeChild(doc.getElementsByTagName("Button").item(0));
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException | IOException | SAXException fileNotFoundException) {fileNotFoundException.printStackTrace();}
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(test.class.getResource("test.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 320, 240);
        stage.setTitle("test");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

this is supposed to delete the button in the first VBox before showing it but it doesn't delete it at all and it doesn't throw any exceptions or anything. What am i doing wrong? or if there's a better way altogether to do this please do tell me.

i should point out the variables { dbf, is and db} aren't null but if i print doc it prints [Document: null] but i read in threads talking about editing XML files that this happens even if it isn't null and sth like

```
System.out.println(doc.getElementsByTagName("VBox").item(0).getNodeName());
```

prints : VBox

Comment: You're simply modifying the in-memory model of the DOM. The file won't change. So when you load the FXML, of course you see the original FXML file.

Comment: Perhaps the [SceneBuilder *Kit*](https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/) (either the binary or source) might have functionality to help you solve your problem.  Perhaps not though, I don’t know.  It is a completely different approach.

Comment: so how should i go about modifying the actual FXML file? or that not the purpose of DOM?

Comment: where can i find the source code for scene builder? since it is made in java it might indeed have that although it might be complicated

Comment: It’s ages since I’ve used the DOM API, but presumably there’s a method for writing the document to an `OutputStream`. Create a `PipedOutputStream`, connect it to a `PipedInputStream`, write the document to the `PipedOutputStream` and pass the `PipedInputStream` to `FXMLLoader.load(…)`.

Comment: This has the feel of an XY question though. There are numerous ways you could do this with just the JavaFX API. Eg just loading the FXML, navigating the scene graph, and removing nodes. Or something similar using CSS lookups. But maybe you have a solid reason for this approach.

Comment: the only thing that matters here is that i'm able to do it with code since i want to integrate in a more complicated setup where there are buttons in the user interface that create new nodes permanently by adding them to the source file.

Comment: You can’t permanently modify a source file. Eg the source “file” at some point will almost certainly be an entry in a jar file, which will not be modifiable. Typical approaches to this are modelling the application state, then you can save the model to the file system. At application startup, read the model in from the file system and arrange for the UI to reflect the model.

Comment: hmm that sounds reasonable. i was trying to avoid modelling the thing because i haven't learned it yet and wanted to start with sth easier. but now that you told me i can't avoid by editing an FXML file then i guess it's time to learn. thank you for your time.

Comment: There are two problems here, one conceptual and one practical. The practical problem is that resources are read-only. While it's definitely possible to edit and save FXML files using Java's XML libraries, you won't be able to replace the existing FXML file that's packaged in your application. The conceptual problem is one of design. When you have a dynamic GUI, where that GUI's appearance can be "persisted", you don't actually want to save the GUI. What you want to save is the state from which the GUI is then built. Note saving/loading a model is likely much easier than what you were trying.

Comment: yeah i'm just gonna forget about my original approach and just learn how saving and reading a model works.

Comment: “where can i find the source code for scene builder?” -> Scene builder and kit source is in [github](https://github.com/gluonhq/scenebuilder). I think the ability to create fxml files from an object model is in the [fxom](https://github.com/gluonhq/scenebuilder/tree/master/kit/src/main/java/com/oracle/javafx/scenebuilder/kit/fxom) package though I didn’t look at in detail to make sure.